Stability state space + bound for other variable
Let us consider a linear state-space model of the form:
$$\dot{e}=Ae+Gd \tag 1$$
where $e$ is the closed-loop error and $d$ an external variable of interest linked nonlinearly to $e$ as $d=h(e)$.
The stability of $e$ is ensured as $A$ is stable.
However, I would like to ensure not only the stability of $e$ but also that $d$ remains bounded for all $e$.
$d$ is not really a perturbation that we want to reject, the closed-loop model is designed such that $d$ follows a given trajectory. But I do not know how to include it into the stability analysis.
I have tried Lyapunov and LMI stability analysis such that $V(e) = e^TPe$ which gives:
$$ \dot{V}<0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}e \\d \end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}A^T+PA & PG \\G^TP & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e \\d \end{pmatrix} \tag 2$$
but this is not feasible due to the 0 on the diagonal.
Any ideas how to overcome this ? I have looked at ISS property but do not know if this could like.
The final objective would like to be able to write something like : $\dot{V}<0$ and $\|d\|<\alpha\|e\|$.
I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance !

The stability of $e$ is not ensured by $\mathbf A$ being stable, because $\dot e$ depends on $e$ via both $\mathbf A e$ and $\mathbf G h(e)$.  Depending on the value of $\mathbf G$ and the characteristics of $h(d)$, the system described in your (1) could be stable or not.
